# How to run script via SSH that doesn't end when I close connection?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bash, gnu-screen, nohup

I need to run script, that takes long time to execute, or I just want it to run forever. I can't just SSH to my machine, because when I disconnect it stops running.

**Is there any way to run script that isn't dependent on the shell that started it?**

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can run the command with the nohup command before it.  You can also run it in 'screen', which will allow you reattach the terminal.

For example:

```
ssh mySever 'nohup bash myscript.sh'
```

Or just ssh into and run the nohup command.  It should keep running even when you disconnect.  This is because the nohup will intercept the SIGHUP singal (hangup).

Screen is a bit more involved, but for the 20 minutes it might take you to learn the basics, it is one of the most useful tools out there.  [Here is a tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20091126075643/http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935).

Comment: Sniped by Kyle...  >smile<

Comment: +1 to anyone who snipes Evan.  Happy 10K :)

Comment: the link to the tutorial is broken :(

Answer (score 10):

I always just use nohup.  If I care about the output, I redirect it to a log file, otherwise I send it to /dev/null.

Example:

```
nohup scp file.tar.gz root@someserver:/var/tmp > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That puts it in the background, with output going to /dev/null, and it is immune to the HUP signal if you log out.  You can also "disown" the job with certain shells (like bash) so that it's not connected to your session.

```
disown %1
```

Comment: +1 for disown - very useful when you forget to run using nohup

Answer (score 8):

To install screen : `apt-get install screen`

Then launch using simply : `screen`

And `man screen` to get the key binding.

Comment: +1!  screen is da thing!

Comment: I used to use screen, but have switched to tmux for a variety of reasons. Google "tmux vs screen" and you will find some links like this:  https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen

Comment: screen/tmux/byobu does much more than preventing the death of running script, a indispensable tool!

Answer (score 2):

While you are logged into a server, you can run a script in detached mode by the following command:

```
nohup script >script.out 2>script.err &
```

Later when you log in again, you can check script.out for any output, and script.err for any error messages. If you want output and error messages in the same file, then do:

```
nohup script >script.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

***Trivia:***  The command name `nohup` comes from "hang-up," as in hanging up the *(of course, "black, rotary-dial" ...)* phone on your 110-baud Teletype machine after removing the headset from its squishy holder.  Usually, when Unix detects that you "hung up," it sends a `SIGHUP` signal to the process.

Answer (score -1):

If you want something you can run non-interactively from the client, try this:

```sh
ssh user@host 'command >out.log 2>err.log &'
```

For example:

```sh
$ ssh user@host '(while true; do date; sleep 1; done) >/tmp/dates &'
$ ssh user@host
...
user@host$ tail -f /tmp/dates
user@host$ ps -ef | grep dates
```

Note however that if you don't redirect the output to files then the ssh invocation won't finish until the command does.

Comment: This will still abort the command when the ssh connection is lost.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I just tried it and it worked fine. Can you give an example where this doesn't work?